# Required request part is not present with react

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am getting "Required request part 'file' is not present."
it works fine with postman but no with react js.
I am trying to call a end point in a Spring boot restfull api.

Following the code:

```
function sendUploadFileRequest(file, userName, caseRef) {
  /* var formData = {
    username: userName,
    caseRef: caseRef,
    file: file
  }; */

  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', file);

  const requestOptions = putRequestWithBodyUploadFile(formData)
  console.log(requestOptions);
  return fetch(
    `${config.apiUrl}/distribution-cases/uploadFileToSharepoint?access_token=${authHeader().Authorization}`,
    requestOptions
  ).then(handleResponse);
}
export function putRequestWithBodyUploadFile(body) {
  return {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {

      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x',

      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type',
      'Access-Control-Request-Method': '*'

    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
}
@PostMapping(value = "/distribution-cases/uploadFileToSharepoint", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Upload a file to sharepoint. This api will upload a file to Sharepoint for the associated user. Once the file has been uploaded  an email will be sent to the case owner. ", httpMethod = "PUT")
    public ResponseEntity<StringBuilder> uploadFileToSharepoint(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was converting the dataForm to json with **JSON.stringify()** in the body of the request. And it is **NOT** needed headers with content = multipart/form-data because the browser handle it automatically.